# When are complete intersections also local complete intersections?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, projective-schemes

First, let us recall some definitions.

> Let $P=\mathbb P^d_k$ be a projective space over a field $k$. Let $X$
>   be a closed subvariety of $P$ of dimension $r$. We say that $X$ is a
>   complete intersection if it is defined (as a variety) by $d-r$
>   homogeneous polynomials $F_1,\dots,F_{d-r}$. This notion depends on
>   the embedding $X\rightarrow P$.
>
> Let $Y$ be a locally Noetherian scheme. Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a
>   morphism of finite type. We say that $f$ is a local complete
>   intersection at $x$ if there exist a neighborhood $U$ of $x$, a scheme
>   $Z$, a regular immersion $i:U\rightarrow Z$, and a smooth morphism
>   $g:Z\rightarrow Y$ such that $f|_U=g\circ i.$

I would like to know when a complete intersection is also a local complete intersection, if we understand this to mean that the inclusion $X\rightarrow \mathbb P^n_k$ is a local complete intersection morphism. I suspect this is always true.

We know $\mathbb P^n_k$ is always locally Noetherian, so that part of the definition is satisfied. I think we can just take $Z=\mathbb P^n_k$ and $U=X$, since I believe the canonical injection will always be regular. I do not know how to prove this, though. This would mean $g$ would have to be the identity. It seems like this is non-smooth for non-smooth varieties.

These thoughts lead me to the following questions.

$1.$ If $X$ is a complete intersection, how can we prove that the injection $X\rightarrow \mathbb P^n_k$ is regular? I know we want to prove the kernel of the map on the stalks is generated by a regular sequence, but I don't know how to carry this out.

$2.$ Are complete intersections always local complete intersections? If not, what hypotheses must we place on $X$ so that this is true? With the choice of $X$ and $Z$ above, this boils down to asking when $g$ is smooth.

(I realize this is a fairly elementary question, but I want to be absolutely sure about the details.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your guess is correct.

First, the notion of smooth for a morphism is intuitively a property about its fibers. The identity map of a scheme is always smooth.

Regular immersion means that at every point of $X$, there is an affine neighborhood where it is cut out by a regular sequence. If $X \subset P^n$ is cut out by $d-r$ polynomials as you say, then you can just take the restrictions of those polynomials to that open set and they will be a regular sequence: since the open set $U$ contains a point of $X$, the dimension of $U \cap X$ is the same as dimension of $X$, and a sequence of length $d-r$ is regular if and only if the zero scheme it cuts out is of codimension $d-r$ (this is a property of Cohen-Macaulay rings, of which the coordinate ring of a smooth affine open set in projective space is a special case).

So in terms of generalizing, everything above would be okay if you replaced projective space with any Cohen-Macaulay scheme (let's say connected to avoid technicalities).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Suppose have made the reduction to a dimension $r$ variety in an affine space of dimension $d$ cut out by $d-r$ polynomials $f_i$. If $\mathfrak p$ is some prime ideal, we want to show that the localization at $\mathfrak p$ of the following map has kernel that is generated by a regular sequence:

$$A[x_j]\rightarrow  A[x_j]/(f_i),$$

yes? [...]

Comment: I believe this means we want to show that the $f_i$, when localized, are a regular sequence in $A[x_j]_{\mathfrak p}$. To do this, I would like to use the lemma that if $(A,\mathfrak m)$ is a Noetherian local ring, and $f\in \mathfrak m$, then $\dim (A/fA)\ge \dim A -1$, with equality when $f$ is not contained in a minimal prime. Does this work? (I can sketch the argument if needed.)

Comment: I'm actually not sure this works. We know equality holds if it's not a zero divisor, but we need the other direction.

Comment: Yes, the other direction holds when the ambient ring is Cohen-Macaulay (every regular ring is Cohen-Macaulay). In general, if an ideal is generated by $d$ elements and quotienting by them drops the dimension by $d$, the sequence is called a system of parameters. Cohen-Macaulay means exactly that every system of parameters is a regular sequence.