# Converse of a dimension lemma

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, krull-dimension, dimension-theory-algebra

Consider the following lemma. It comes from the [Stacks Project](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00KD).

> **Lemma 9.59.11.** Suppose that $R$ is a Noetherian local ring and
>   $x\in\mathfrak m$ an element of its maximal ideal. Then $\dim R\le
>  \dim R/xR+1$. If $x$ is not contained in any of the minimal primes of
>   $R$ then equality holds. (For example if $x$ is a nonzerodivisor.)

Does the converse hold? Precisely, if equality holds above in the statement above, is $x$ not a zerodivisor? If this is not true, can we add a set of reasonable hypotheses and make it true?

(I strongly suspect it does hold, but I would like confirmation.)

Comment: @YACP I'm certainly appreciative of the answers I get, but I ran out of votes yesterday. Could you please undelete your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is the following: the equality holds iff $x$ is part of a system of parameters. Since in a Cohen-Macaulay ring systems of parameters are regular sequences (and viceversa), then you can easily deduce your answer.

$\textbf{}$

Comment: Still, I think it's the most complete answer. I accepted it and will upvote it when my votes recharge.

Comment: Haha, my bad. Fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

I think the converse does not hold.  Take $R=k[[x,y]]/(x^2, xy)$, where $k$ is a field, and mod out by $y$.

Comment: @Potato In this example $y$ is a system of parameters but not a regular element, and this happens since $R$ is not Cohen-Macaulay.

Answer (score 0):

According to the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/442840/18240) by Steven Sam, the other direction holds if the ambient ring is Cohen-Macaulay. In particular, all regular rings are Cohen-Macaulay.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francis_Sowerby_Macaulay

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I would have appreciated a more direct comment, but point taken.